# What is the aliases array in fs.files for?

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

I want to learn more about MongoDB's GridFS so I had a look at the [manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/gridfs/#files.aliases).

It says:

> **files.aliases**
>   Optional. An array of alias strings.

I know that this field may contain an array of strings, but what are the values inside this array used for? Alternative filenames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. For instance, from the MongoDB csharp driver source code ([MongoGridFSFileInfo.cs, ln 474](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/GridFS/MongoGridFSFileInfo.cs)):

```
// copy all createOptions except Aliases (which are considered alternate filenames)
```

However, it's rather unclear what the semantics of this field are. The csharp driver, for instance, won't look for aliases when you search by name. As far as I can see, there's not even an index on aliases, so searching on that field is practically impossible.

In general, keep in mind that GridFS is a mere concept of how to store large files in MongoDB - the implementation isn't special in any way - it's just regular collections and conventions, plus the command line tools. While the general idea of GridFS is neat, it does come with a lot of assumptions and conventions that you might not want to deal with, and that can be painful to work with in statically typed languages. You can always build your own GridFS with a different fieldset, though.

Comment: So it's never being used anywhere and even the writers of the documentation don't know what it is for? I think that field may be kicked out in future releases.

Comment: I just noticed that it's deprecated now. :)